# SSIS - Combine Event Handler Error Description in C#

Tags: c#, ssis

I need to send an e-mail that provides any errors during a package's execution. I was able to do this with the "Send Mail Task", however it sends an e-mail every time the event handler receives an error, resulting in multiple e-mails. I know this is working as intended, and I would like to combine the errors into a variable object, then send the object in an e-mail, however my C# skills are not very good. Can anyone help me with this?

Right now, I have a SSIS variable object named User::CompleteErrorDescription and I've placed it in the Event Handler for the whole package with a script task and the following code:

```
        public void Main()
    {
        // TODO: Add your code here

        List<string> NewList = new List<string>();

      NewList.Add(Dts.Variables["System::ErrorDescription"].Value);

        Dts.Variables["User::CompleteErrorDescription"].Value = NewList;

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

This does not work as I will need each ErrorDescription to append to User::CompleteErrorDescription. I don't know how to write this in C#. Furthermore, a variable of type object can't be used in Message Source for a Send Email Task. I'm not sure how to handle that.

Comment: Providing what you have so far, what you have tried, will help anyone on here help you.  Without your code it is more difficult to provide a solution that would work with what you have already.  But should be easy, where you check and send email, just append the error to your variable value.  Then at end of package if variable value is not null, send email with all errors.  (again if you had your code could provide more specific example)

Comment: @Brad I've added additional information about my code. Hopefully this will be helpful to find a solution.

Comment: What is the data type for your CompleteErrorDescription?  Your setting it as a list so in SSIS it would have to be an OBJECT data type?